Completely non- normal matrix
Let $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be the space of $n \times n$ matrices with complex entries. A matrix $N$ is said to be normal if $N^*N=NN^*$ where $N^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $N$. One can think of a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as a linear operator
acting on $\mathbb{C}^n$ in the following way:
$L_A: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ given by $L_A(x)=Ax$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$.
Without any confusion, we denote $L_A$ by $A$ only. A matrix $A$ acting on $\mathbb{C}^n$ is said to be completely non-normal if there is no non-trivial subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$  that is invariant under $A$ and $A^*$ (i.e., reducing subspace) restricted to which $A$ acts as a normal matrix.
I have a confusion with $2 \times 2$ case. As per my understanding, any matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\
0 & a 
\end{bmatrix}$ for $a, b \ne 0$ must be a completely non-normal matrix. Evidently, $A$ is not normal. Now, any non-trivial reducing subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$ must be one dimensional and if $A$ is not completely non-normal, then $A=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & 0 \\
0 & a_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ with respect to the decomposition $\mathbb{C}^2=W \oplus W^\perp$. This implies that $A$ is normal which is a contradiction. I know for the fact that this is not true though. What point I am missing here?

The proof is correct: you assumed $A$ was not completely non-normal and you obtained a contradiction. what is your doubt?

@Exodd I have matrix of the above form which is not completely non-matrix. For example, take $\begin{bmatrix} a & a(1-a)^2 \ 0 & a \end{bmatrix}$ for $0<a<1$.

The matrix you wrote has no nontrivial invariant subspace for both $A$ and $A^*$

@Exodd So, such a matrix must be completely non-normal since it has no non-trivial subspace invariant under $A$ and $A^*$. But this is not true.

why is it so? How do you prove it is not non-normal?

@Exodd For any $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$, the kernel of $A^nA^{*m}-A^{*m}A^n$ is trivial for the given $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & a(1-a)^2 \ 0 & a \end{bmatrix}$. Thus, $A$ cannot have any non-trivial reducing subspace on which $A$ becomes normal.

you just proved that it is completely non-normal

@Exodd yeah but it should not be.

but IT IS NON-NORMAL. Why are you convinced it is not????

@Exodd because of the Theorem which I attached above.

What is $A_2$? Also, you need a norm 1 operator, so you have relations between $a,b$, have you tried computing them?

The norm of the matrix $A$ is
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\
0 & a 
\end{bmatrix}\implies \| A \| = \frac 12 \left(|b| + \sqrt{|b|^2 + 4|a|^2} \right) $$
(for a proof see Corollary 2 from the same article of your theorem), so it has norm 1 exactly when $|b| = 1-|a|^2$.
As a consequence, both Theorem 3 and your proof hold on the same matrix, that is completely non-normal.
If you want to prove that $A$ is non-normal for any $a,b\ne 0$, just divide by $\|A\|\ne 0$ and apply the same Theorem. Complete non-normality in fact is invariant by multiplication of non-zero scalars.
